# Flash zips in download mode

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, recovery-mode, odin

I have an old Galaxy Ace II with no installed ROM and stock recovery, and I am trying to put a custom recovery/ROM on it but all I can find is flashable zips intended for flashing in recovery. I cannot transfer them to the phone as `adb` reports the filesystem as read-only (`adb shell` tells me the shell doesn't exist).

I don't know whether what I'm trying to do is possible, I don't know if I'm being stupid, but is there a way of transferring or flashing the zips in download mode using Odin/Heimdall, or is it possible of transferring the files to the phone any other way?

EDIT: [Recovery download](https://send.firefox.com/download/d1e2a05143/#eyaf23SsHwhgPIm3j0rhRQ)

Comment: Huh? Flash a custom recovery (e.g. [TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-ace/ace-2-develop/recovery-twrp-2-8-6-0-t3086039)) via Odin first. Check out the subforum in [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-ace/ace-2-develop) for more stuff.

Comment: Problem is there doesn't seem to be any. There is one CWM recovery flashable via odin and the download link is dead, and one TWRP download which flashes ok but has some serious issues (no adb, can't mount /sdcard) rendering it useless

Comment: It is not possible to flash zip files in Odin Mode, as far as I know, because the component which answers Odin/Heimdall has no knowledge of zip files and the like.

Comment: Would it be possible to reconstruct the zips into a format it can read and how hard is that likely to be? I'd only need to do it for TWRP

Comment: @JakeStanger Could you either upload or link to the zip you are dealing with?

Comment: Added a download link

Comment: Wait what? You mean the one I pointed you to in the comments has issues? Please make clear your exact model number and last official firmware version - there might be some incompatibility going on.

Comment: Oh sorry I completely missed your link. Yes, I had some pretty severe issues with that one (no adb and couldn't mount internal storage). I don't have access to the phone at the moment but if once I do I've still got trouble I'll get back to you.

Comment: @JakeStanger Your link has expired, so let's test Andy's idea.

Comment: Unable to mount internal storage is probably because TWRP can't handle encryption of stock `/data`. You might also ask in that XDA thread if anyone has a similar phenomenon.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry to waste your time here but after hours of searching I eventually found a ported Odin-flashable version of TWRP buried in the depths of some XDA thread. I will however keep your comments in mind if ever I have a similar experience.